# gradle wrapper not overriding default wrapper properties

Tags: gradle, gradlew

We are using gradle wrapper for our project
There is a gradle-wrapper.properties generated as part of the wrapper

We would like to know whether the gradle-wrapper.properties in the wrapper will over ride the gradle.properties available in the user home directory.
For eg: if Developer has a different gradle installation and has a gradle.properties in his machine, and when we enforce gradle wrapper, we observed that the local gradle.properties is considered for build.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [gradle properties file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html#N24FBB) specifies the properties to be used by gradlew script, like what version to download and use, and not properties for the build process.

Moreover, the gradle.properties file should be shipped along with your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.